# JWT Decode retuning null even when Token is not null

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

JWT Decode is not working

I've tried everything I could

```
let user_id = jwt.decode(req.body.auth_token).id;
```

req.body.auth_token is not null, it's returning the token!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was using JSON.Stringify in AsyncStorage in React Native... Now I'm using this.setState and it's working :-D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are referring to `id` property before it decodes token. Try to do sth like this:

```
`const your_fnc = async (token) => {
  let user_id = await jwt.decode(req.body.auth_token)
  user_id = user_id.id
}`
```

Comment: what decode algorithm are you using? can you give me an example of token?

Comment: I'm using const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

Token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVjYjkxNWNmNmM1NDUwMWY2ODkxZDJiNSIsImlhdCI6MTU1NTk4OTY5OCwiZXhwIjoxNTU2MDc2MDk4fQ.adCPEF38dkgEPlPGDaSBpXtIUMAr8BKqf0EIfHkDxCo